# Unserialize in ActionScript 3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, amfphp, serialization

I have an array that I am constructing in PHP which I am serializing then returning to Flex through AMFPHP.  Can someone point me towards a solution for unserilizing said data once it gets into Flex via ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways. If you use something like the `RemoteObject` class, they will be automatically deserialized. This is how I prefer to do things. However, if all you've got is a `ByteArray` if serialized objects, you can use the `read{Object,Int,...}` methods to read the data it contains.

Comment: If you can tell me how the data is getting into Flex, I might be able to offer some more help.